# Python OpenCV2: Trying to use the HoughLine Transform for small line segments

Tags: python, line, detection, opencv3.0

My code:

```
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/vinay/Desktop/hi.jpg')
imageResize = cv2.resize(image, (900,1200))
grayImage = cv2.Canny(imageResize,100,200,apertureSize=3,L2gradient=True)
finalGray = cv2.resize(grayImage, (900, 1200))
rows, columns = finalGray.shape
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(finalGray,1, np.pi/180, 200, minLineLength=0,   maxLineGap=100)

#Or lines = cv2.HoughLine() -- don't know what parameters to use

for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(picture, (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)

cv2.imwrite('FinalGrayTest.jpg', picture)
```

Image after Edge Detection:

[image]

My problem:

So if you see the image, there are two small squares beneath the big vertical rectangles. I'm trying to use the Hough Line Transform. How would I use it? What parameters should I use for the HoughLineP() or is the HoughLine method better? What parameters would I need for that? How would I also traverse through the list using the cv2.line() method and what parameters do I need to put in that method. 
I'm am currently only am able to draw big straight lines. 
Thank You!

Comment: Could you add the initial picture?